# Connect a linked server to MS Reporting Service?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, ssrs

I've got a MYSQL server setup as a linked server in MS SQL server 2008. Can someone tell me if it is possible to generate reports from this server?

How do I connect it to Reporting Services?

Comment: In your comment below you mention Report Model, there is a good bit of difference between a Report Model project and a Report Server project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a stored procedure which selects the desired data and call it from your report as you call any other procedure. If you want to avoid having stored procedure just put the query directly into the report. You do need to use Mysql provider, just use a sql provider.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any problems generating reports the usual way, as long as you use the 4 part name:
'select top 10 col1, col2 from server.database.schema.table' in the code used to get the data for your reports.

Comment: But, when I create a Report Model project, I don't seem to have the option to use my connection to MYSQL as a data source? I only seem to have two provider options - 'SQLClientDataProvider' and 'OracleClientDataProvider'.